# Show that $2\mathrm{AB}+2\mathrm{BC}+2\mathrm{CA}>4\mathrm{AT}+3\mathrm{BT}+2\mathrm{CT}$.

Tags: geometry, inequality, euclidean-geometry, maxima-minima, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

> Inside a triangle $\triangle\mathrm{ABC}$ we consider the point $\mathrm{T}$ which has the property that
> $$\angle\mathrm{BTC} = \angle\mathrm{CTA} = \angle\mathrm{ATB}.$$
>
> Show that:
> $$2\mathrm{AB}+2\mathrm{BC}+2\mathrm{CA}>4\mathrm{AT}+3\mathrm{BT}+2\mathrm{CT}$$

Okey, so I am going to attach a photo where there are all my ideas. I just arrive at the point that

$$ 2\mathrm{AB} + 2\mathrm{BC} + 2\mathrm{CA} < 4\mathrm{AT} + 4\mathrm{BT} + 4\mathrm{CT}. $$

I hope my idea can help you think of a solution. I don't know what to do alone and hope you can help me. Any ideas are welcome.

[image: Triangle]

\begin{gather}
\angle\mathrm{BTC} = \angle\mathrm{CTA} = \angle\mathrm{ATB} = \frac{360^{\circ}}{3} = 120^{\circ}. \\
\mathrm{AB} + \mathrm{BC} + \mathrm{CA} = P(\triangle\mathrm{ABC}) \\
\mathrm{AT} + \mathrm{BT} + \mathrm{CT} \\
\end{gather}

For $\text{BAT}$ to be a $\triangle$, it must be

\begin{align*}
\textsf{REPEAT}
&\quad\implies\quad
\begin{cases}
\mathrm{AT} + \mathrm{BT} > \mathrm{AB} \\
\mathrm{BT} + \mathrm{CT} > \mathrm{BC} \\
\mathrm{CT} + \mathrm{AT} > \mathrm{CA}
\end{cases} \\[0.5em]
&\quad\implies\quad
2\mathrm{AT} + 2\mathrm{BT} + 2\mathrm{CT} > \mathrm{AB} + \mathrm{BC} + \mathrm{CA} \\[0.5em]
&\quad\implies\quad
4\mathrm{AT} + 4\mathrm{BT} + 4\mathrm{CT} > 2\mathrm{AB} + 2\mathrm{BC} + 2\mathrm{CA}.
\end{align*}
\begin{gather}
\mathrm{AB} > \mathrm{AT} \\
\mathrm{AB} > \mathrm{BT}
\end{gather}

<sup>[(Original image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPhw2.jpg)</sup>

Comment: Please avoid using pictures for displaying formulas. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Sorry for using the picture. It was easier for me to upload. I will take your advice!

Comment: Where did you find this problem, btw?

Comment: I found it in a math gathering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say $AT = a$, $BT=b$ and $CT =c$ and $AB=x$, $BC=y$ and $CA=z$. Then by the cosine theorem and special case of Cauchy inequality: $$(k^2+m^2)(1+1)\geq (k+m)^2$$we have $$x^2 = a^2+b^2 +ab = (b+{a\over 2})^2 +{3a^2\over 4} \geq {1\over 2}(b+{a\over 2} +{a\sqrt{3}\over 2})^2$$

and thus $$x\geq {1\over \sqrt{2}} (b+{a\over 2} +{a\sqrt{3}\over 2})$$
similary $$z\geq {1\over \sqrt{2}} (c+{a\over 2} +{a\sqrt{3}\over 2})$$ and $$y\geq {1\over \sqrt{2}} (c+{b\over 2} +{b\sqrt{3}\over 2})$$

Now the double sum of all expression on the right is greater than $4a+3b+2c$ (this is easy to verify) and you are done.

Comment: But the cosine theoreme isn't x^2 =a^2+b^2-2*a*b*cos C

Comment: @IonelaBuciu Yes, and?

Comment: i dont understand how you got to first inequality. can you please explain all the steps?

Comment: So, I understand how you applied the cosine theorem, but can you explain me how you applied the inequality of Cauchy?

Comment: I did, I wrote Cauchy inequality. Have you checked?

Comment: What is Cauchy inequality?

Comment: idk how you arrived to(b+a/2)^2+3a^2/4≥1/2(b+a^2+3*a^2)^2

Comment: $m =b+a/2$ and $k=\sqrt{3}a/2$.

Comment: Ummm... i tried demonstrating it from where you let me but it foes to nothing

Comment: Perhas the other solution is better. Have you read it?

Comment: I dont think so....... i didn't understand it because I didn't learn it in school

Comment: It seems to me that your solution is much easier. Thank you from the bottom of my heart for the idea!

Answer (score 1):

The point $T$ is called the [Torricelli point or Fermat–Torricelli point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_point) and there is a connected construction of a equilateral triangle (you can also see it in the wiki page). Denote the sides of the initial triangle by $a,b,c$ and the segments $TA, TB$ and $TC$ by $x,y$ and $z$. Using the construction with equilateral triangle you can show the inequalities
$$
c + a > x + y + z,\qquad b + c > x + y + z.
$$
Now it is left to show $b + a > 2x + y$. WLOG, we can assume that $z\le x$ and $z\le y$ In this case $\angle C \le 60^{\circ}$ and again via the equilateral triangle, you can show $(x + y) + x < 2c \le a + b$.